# How to handle quotes, double quotes etc

Tags: jsp

Im making a jsp form to save data on a db.

I have to manage characters like `“ " ' ‘`, so i'm trying to make a method that turn that characters into HTML Code.

This is my code

jsp page

```
<jsp:useBean id="GestioneTesto" class="Jeans.GestioneTesto"/>
out.println(GestioneTesto.getTestoParsato(‘testo‘));
```

this is the bean

```
public class GestioneTesto {

    public String getTestoParsato(String text_to_replace){


    String replaced_text = text_to_replace.replaceAll("‘", "&lsquo;");      


    return replaced_text;
    }

}
```

when i call getTestoParsato i have again  `‘testo‘`  and not  `&lsquo;testo&lsquo;`.

Comment: Why do you want to replace `\\“` instead of just `“`?

Comment: Why don't you simply use UTF8, and avoid encoding everything except HTML special chars (`<`, `>`, `"`, `'` and `&`, which are all encoded by `<c:out>` and `fn:escapeXml()`)

Comment: I set the charset with **<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />**, but when i try to save what a user write in my form, mysql can't save that character, so i thought i should use html code.

Comment: That's a MySQL problem, not a presentation problem. Ang you should never store HTML-encoded characters in your database: think what would happen if you want to use the same data for a non-HTML app.